# Why do my SQLite entries into table have same datestamp?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
import time
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
import time
import datetime
import sqlite3
root = Tk()
id = 1

conn = sqlite3.connect('temp_sensor2.db')
c = conn.cursor()

sensor = W1ThermSensor()
temperature = sensor.get_temperature()

t = int(time.time())
date = str (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
global tempLabel1


def get_temp(period_ms):

    temperature = sensor.get_temperature()
    tempLabel1['text'] = temperature
    tempLabel1.after(period_ms, get_temp, period_ms)

    c.execute('''INSERT INTO datetemp VALUES (?, ?, ?)''',(id, date, temperature));
    conn.commit()

root.title('Temperature')

tempLabel2 = Label(root, text="Temperature is ")
tempLabel2.pack()
tempLabel1 = Label(root, width=25)
tempLabel1.pack()

get_temp(1000)


root.mainloop()
```

I have a program here that monitors temperature and automatically updates in a tkinter label. I also wish to have it update a SQLite DB, however it enters multiple entries into the table with the exact same datestamp (although temperature reading will be different). Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you ever assign a new value to `date` so it updates? (You're also better off using a [format recognized by sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), and just changing your insert to `INSERT INTO datetemp VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)` if you want the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = int(time.time())
date = str (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

These two lines of code run once, when your program starts up, and the `date` variable never changes after that.

If you move these lines inside the `get_temp()` function, then it will use the current timestamp.

Comment: Hi John, Yes that's all it was! The variables were not being updates inside the function once they were ran the first time. Thank you for your response, it's so obvious now - think I was staring at it too long!